# Core Bluetooth CBCentralManager always reports state as Unknown on Mac

Tags: ios, macos, bluetooth

I'm new to Swift and Mac/iOs programming in general. I'm running this sample on a Macbook Pro with BLE support and with Bluetooth turned on, using Xcode 7.3.

```
import Foundation
import CoreBluetooth

func printState(state: CBCentralManagerState) {
    switch state {
    case CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOn:
        print("Powered on")
    case CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOff:
        print("Powered off")
    case CBCentralManagerState.Resetting:
        print("Resetting")
    case CBCentralManagerState.Unauthorized:
        print("Unauthorized")
    case CBCentralManagerState.Unknown:
        print("Unknown")
    default:
        print ("Unsupported")
    }

}

var myCentralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate:nil, queue:nil)
while true {
    printState(myCentralManager.state)
    sleep(1)
}
```

The code prints out "Unknown" over and over, even after many minutes. I've also tried setting up a delegate but the didUpdateState callback doesn't called. I've also tried to run this from the command line and Swift interpreter and get the same result.

I must be missing something very basic. How can I get it to report that the CBCentralManager is powered on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Near as I can tell, if you don't use one of the two initializers listed in the documentation, this is the result -- you want to use either:

```
init(delegate:queue:)
```

or:

```
init(delegate:queue:options:)
```

Xcode doesn't complain if you just call:

```
CBCentralManager()
```

but if you do that, it seems like you'll stay in `CBCentralManagerState.Unknown` indefinitely.

If you want to experiment, make a playground and paste this code, and try it with the two initializer variants I've listed:

```
import Cocoa
import CoreBluetooth
import XCPlayground

@objc
public class BluetoothWatcher: NSObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate {
    var cbcm: CBCentralManager!;
    var timer: NSTimer!;

    override init() {
        super.init();

        /*:
            When you initialize a central manager, the delegate seems important. If you comment out the initializer with the delegate and uncomment the other one, it'll stay in state unknown indefinitely.
        */
        //cbcm = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue:nil);
        cbcm = CBCentralManager();

        checkStateInOneSecond();
    }

    public func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager) {
        print( "State updated: \(stateString())" );
    }

    func checkStateInOneSecond() {
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (Int64)(1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.checkState();
        });
    }

    public func checkState() {
        print( "Timer fired, state: \(stateString())" );
        checkStateInOneSecond();
    }

    func stateString() -> String {
        switch(cbcm.state) {
        case .Resetting:
            return "resetting"
        case .PoweredOn:
            return "powered on";
        case .PoweredOff:
            return "powered off";
        case .Unknown:
            return "unknown";
        case .Unsupported:
            return "unsupported";
        case .Unauthorized:
            return "unauthorized";
        }
    }
}


XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true;
var watcher = BluetoothWatcher();
```

You'll see with the delegate, it starts in `Unknown`, and almost immediately the delegate gets called with a state change to `PoweredOn`, and every subsequent timer fire shows `PoweredOn`.

Do the same thing without the delegate, with the empty initializer, and the delegate method will never be called (no surprise) and the timer fires will continue to show `Unknown`.

Comment: Got it working with the delegate. I had tried this before but it wasn't working because I didn't put in a call to dispatch_main

Comment: This is absolutely correct.  Thanks for saving me hours more of banging my  head against the desk.